# Lambda + API Gateway: optional proxy param

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I've made a Lambda / API Gateway function that has a proxy param as the final param in the URL.

```
  page:
    handler: handlers/website/getRenderedPage.get
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: /content/{website}/{proxy+}
          cors: true
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                proxy: true
                website: true
```

So, as defined, this is the behavior I'm experiencing:

- `/content/site.com/blog/hello-world` --> `website: site.com, proxy: blog/hello-world` --> URL works successfully in browser.
- `/content/site.com` --> `website: site.com` --> URL fails in browser (missing authentication token, aka API resource not found).

Is it possible to make that `{proxy+}` parameter optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have it listen to two events.

- `/content/{website}` and
- `/content/{website}/{proxy+}`

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but I recently ran into resource limits in my CF template, so I was hoping to eliminate a few endpoints

Comment: Well, the `/` means you need to separate them. What happens if you call `/content/site.com/` instead?